# Open up Eclipse Editor in a dialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have a requirement where I need to open my editor in a dialog.

The things I have are

1. My Editor Plugin
2. A button listener in a different plugin where I need to open this editor in a dialog

I tried one way , below is code inside that button listener

```
//this opens up a new workbench window
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow("<provide perspective id here>", null);
//this gets active window, which is the above one and opens our editor
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().openEditor(myEditorInput, "editor.plugin.id");
```

But using above I have to hide a thousands of things from that newly opened window like Menu Bar, Other Views.

My question is can anyone help me opening the editor in a newly created dialog which comes without those menu bars and views.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does not support opening editors in a dialog. Editors rely on too many things in the Eclipse framework which are not available in a dialog.

You can use the JFace `SourceViewer` or `TextViewer` classes which form the core of many text editor in a dialog.

Comment: Greg, this implies change in my editor plugin, right ?

Comment: Yes, the normal TextEditor class is based on SourceViewer but you would have to write something that only uses SourceViewer.

Comment: Very clarifying for me ! I am not supposed to do changes in the editor plugin now, rather will switch to using WorkbenchWindow and hiding unnecessary views. 
Thanks Greg !