# New eclipse workbench window always on top

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an eclipse plugin.

My plugin works in say "XYZ" workbench window.

My plugin opens up a new workbench window say "ABC" using

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().openWorkbenchWindow(PERSPECTIVE_ID, null);
```

now , I want this window("ABC") to be always on top of previous window "XYZ", which in turn means, no one can use the window "XYZ" until some operations('Close', 'Ok', 'Cancel') happen on window "ABC" ......

Can someone help me with this, please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a Dialog rather than a workbench window which doesn't work like that.

Comment: Hey Greg, there we are again.....
I had already questioned this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603527/open-up-eclipse-editor-in-a-dialog

which forces me to use workbench window

Comment: Thanks for quick reply anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make Workbench Windows work like this.

You either have to use a dialog or deal with the fact that the other workbench windows can be used.